# Mysql memory usage increasing after upgrading to 8 and converting some tables from MyISAM to InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb, memory, mysql-8.0

I am having an issue with MySQL gradually consuming more memory every day which seems to have coincided with converting some tables from MyISAM to InnoDB two weeks ago. You can see the trend in [memory usage](https://prnt.sc/wc2it6) .

I am running a server with 4GB RAM and a LAMP stack. My web site traffic hasn't changed much over this time. The traffic is very seasonal though and typical %MEM for mysqld in previous years at this time was in the 15-20% range.

Also of note is that I upgraded to MySQL 8.0 in November (prior to the memory trace shown in the link). I guess I thought the upgrade and conversion of most tables to InnoDB would help performance. And performance is fine, but this memory increase is troubling and I assume it will eventually degrade performance.

Here if my my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
disable-log-bin=1
default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
default-storage-engine=innodb
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_buffer_pool_size=1024M
innodb_log_file_size=128M
max_connections=500
# query_cache_type=2
skip_name_resolve
performance_schema=off
key_buffer_size = 300M
max_allowed_packet=128M
open_files_limit=40000
local_infile=on
```

Any guidance would be appreciated!

**Update (Jan 1 2021):**
I made the following changes...

- Converted remaining tables to InnoDB
- Made data types/collation consistent across all tables
- changed innodb_buffer_pool_size 1024M -> 1280M
- changed key_buffer_size 300M -> 10M
- turned performance schema on

I restarted mysql about 12 hours ago and memory usage is already at where it was before the restart and is continuing to increase linearly with time. CPU usage was always pretty low, but it's even marginally lower with the improvement in join efficiency. I am puzzled.

One thing I noticed is that I set the buffer pool to 1280M, but Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total is shown as 131072 which means the the buffer pool size is actual 2GB. Can I not set the pool to a value between 1GB and 2GB?

Comment: I cannot provide you with a full, proper answer, but you should reduce your key buffer size if no longer using myisam and checking memory allocated to the performance schema.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on performance schema. I'll turn that on. I plan to reduce key_buffer_size, but I still have a few MyISAM tables whose keys take up about 200MB. I do plan to switch them over to InnoDB once I get a handle on the memory issues.

Comment: Then the issue is mostly that using 2 separate engines heavily is likely to cause more memory needs, as tou have 2 "database backends" running in parallel. Note I mentioned P_S as a way to save memory if disabled, it is a very useful tool, but memory hunggry. You can use it where memory is being allocated and tune it to save more.

Comment: Makes sense that using the 2 engines is suboptimal. It is just hard to understand how memory consumption in MySQL 8 is twice (and continuing to increase) from when I was running 5.6 despite little change in the underlying database structure and incoming requests.

Comment: How much RAM?  How big is your dataset?

Comment: 4GB RAM. Data is 1980 MB tables + indexes. 104 tables. On issue I see is that some of my tables have varchar indexes and in 8.0 the default collation has changed. Some of my tables have the collation set as table default, but others have it hard-coded as utf8 and that is causing some performance issues when joining.

Comment: Added an update to the original post. Things are going from weird to weirder.

Comment: Welcome to SE. Additional information request. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) STATUS;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Thanks, @WilsonHauck. Memory usage appears to have stabilized although it is at 1.9g when the size of innodb_buffer_pool_size + permance_schema is 1.5g, so I am surprised at that. Also, I still don't understand why memory usage is so much higher with the upgrade to 8 and moving tables from MyISAM to InnoDB, unless I was running the default innodb_buffer_pool_size of 128M before the upgrade. That seems unlikely given there was a line setting the size to 1028M in my.cnf after I upgraded. Anyway, given that things are stable, I will hold off on further investigation unless things change.

Comment: Congratulations on the stability.  Please view our profile, Network profile for contact info and free downloadable Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning, specifically findfragtables.com could be very helpful for your instance.  Posting additional info requested on Jan 3, 2021 at 21:47 would allow suggestions to improve performance.